# how can i agregate datas from different collections in mongodb using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, find, aggregation-framework

I am using mongoDB and nodejs
I have 4 collections 
collection 1 is teacher with fields teacher_id, teacher_name
collection 2 is subject with fieldssubject _id, subject_name
collection 3 is book with fields book_id, book_name

collection  is student which have fields -- _id, student_name, teacher_id, subject_id, book_id

how can I fetch ids from 1, 2, 3 collections simultaneously and insert to corresponding id in collection

I have tried some which always ask for a matching field... is ther any function which returns data from collection even though no match field?

can someone please help

Comment: In MongoDB, collections are joined using```$lookup```. For more read here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: seems like lokkup need a matching field in all collectipns

Comment: but I don't have a field in my all collections

Comment: I adding the answer according to this conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that case, you need to fetch all the documents from those collections. That will be a bit costly aggregation but I'm adding here in code:

Firstly, I'm grouping on null, to avoid to attach lookup value to every single document in teacher collection.

```
db.teacher.aggregate([
  {
    $group:{
      "_id":null,
      "root":{
        $push:"$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
  $lookup:
   {
     from:"subject",
     pipeline: [],
     as: "subjectLookup"
   }
  },
  {
  $lookup:
   {
     from:"book",
     pipeline: [],
     as: "bookLookup"
   }
  },
  {
  $lookup:
   {
     from:"student",
     pipeline: [],
     as: "studentLookup"
   }
  }
]).pretty()
```

These lookups will give the array which contains all the documents from respective collections, you can limit the documents by adding `$match` stage in the pipeline of lookup stage.

Hope this will solve your problem :)

Comment: Well that you need to figure out, I work mostly with JAVA. :(
I can only help you with MongoDB.